# Flutter Constructor - setter is not defined

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to map JSON to a class using the constructor below but am receiving the error shown.

> Error: The setter 'id' isn't defined for the class 'Marker'.

I am unsure why the id (and the other properties) are not defined.

```
class Marker {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final double lat;
  final double lng;

  //Constructor
  Marker.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
      id = int.tryParse(json['id'].toString());
      name = json['name'].toString();
      lat = double.tryParse(json['lat'].toString());
      lng = double.tryParse(json['lng'].toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct way of creating a model class. Use this model in your app.

```
class Marker {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final double lat;
  final double lng;

  Marker({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.lat,
    required this.lng,
  });

  factory Marker.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Marker(
      id: map['id'],
      name: map['name'],
      lat: double.tryParse(map['lat'].toString()) ?? 0.0, // Default value if parsing fails
      lng: double.tryParse(map['lng'].toString()) ?? 0.0, // Default value if parsing fails
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
      'lat': lat,
      'lng': lng,
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).